# Javascript array to URL encoded string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on the datalayer of a website and I am required to pass a string filled in with values from the site's backend.

Here is the structure of the variable I need to pass:

**> Before encoding:**

> transaction_id=0815/2009;transaction_cid=54AB;item_id=402163045080;item_va
>   lue=25.20;item_quantity=1;
>   transaction_id=0815/2009;transaction_cid=54AB;item_id=402163045080;item_va
>   lue=25.20;item_quantity=1;

**> After encoding:**

> transaction_id%3D0815%2F2009%3Btransaction_cid%3D54AB%3Bitem_id%3D40216304
>   5080%3Bitem_value%3D25.20%3Bitem_quantity%3D1%3Bitem_id%3D847163029054%3Bi
>   tem_value%3D16.81%3Bitem_quantity%3D2

I have managed to create an array with the necessary data in this form:

> '[{"transaction_id":"233684","transaction_cid":"d2871c13c507583048d8ecf4a16f94c0","i
>                   tem_id":"3524","item_value":"4915.13","item_quantity":"1"}]',

But what I need is all these elements of the array in a url encoded string.

I am out of ideas since all that I try seems to not work.

Using JSON.stringify keeps the ":" and the """, using alert() or join also keeps the ":" and is not performant.

***EDIT:***

**Example array:**

```
arr : {key1: 'a', key2:'b', key3:'c'}
```

**non encoded result:**

```
str : 'key1=a;key2=b;key3=c'
```

**desired result:**

str : 'key1%3Da%3Bkey2%3Db%3Bkey3%3Dc'

Comment: Show how you create the array, would be simpler to fix it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `JSON.stringify` with `encodeURIComponent`:

So, in the example above you have an array with one object.  To parse that, I would do:

```
var params = elementArray[0];
var encoded_params = [];
for (var prop in params){
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {            
        encoded_params.push(prop+ "=" +encodeURIComponent(params[prop]));
    }
}
var query_string = "?" + encoded_params.join("&");
```

**NOTE:**
I would prefer to solve this from the beginning, w/ the original string you have:

> transaction_id=0815/2009;transaction_cid=54AB;item_id=402163045080;item_va lue=25.20;item_quantity=1;

```
// break string into components by splitting on `;`:
var data_as_str = "transaction_id=0815/2009;transaction_cid=54AB;item_id=402163045080;item_va lue=25.20;item_quantity=1;";
var raw_params = data_as_str.split(";");

// create a new array where we will store our encoded params
var encoded_params = [];

// traverse the split string components
for (var i=0; i<raw_params.length; i++){
    var element = raw_params[i];

     // check that the element exists 
     // for example, the trailing `;` will create an empty element
     // which we do not want to include
    if (!element){
        continue;
    }

    // split on `=` to get key, value
    var key = element.split("=")[0];
    var value = encodeURIComponent(element.split("=")[1]);

    // build a new param string and push to clean array
    encoded_params.push(key+ "=" +value);
}

// after loop has completed, join elements 
// in clean array to complete query string
var query_string = "?" + encoded_params.join("&");
alert(query_string);
```

Comment: Hey Jordan thanks for the answer but i specified it doesnt work

Comment: This won't create query params

Comment: hmm - maybe i'm misunderstanding the question.  after encoding the urls, do you need to combine them into a query string?

Comment: Clearly says : *"I need is all these elements of the array in a url encoded string"*

Comment: Updated to build the query_string

Comment: @johan855 - can you confirm if this solution has helped you?

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for your answer, I dont really start out from that string you used. The main string I start out from is in my edit, the one formated as a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery you can use [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) . If you don't, you can loop over the keys of Object and format your QueryString. In the example I use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of keys, [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the keys and return a new Array, the ES6 `template String`. With [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) you get t he encoded QueryString.

```js
var obj = {key1: 'a', key2:'b', key3:'c'};

console.log(encodeURIComponent($.param(obj)));

console.log(encodeURIComponent(Object.keys(obj).map(key=>`${key}=${obj[key]}`).join('&')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As pointed in the other answer, you can do this from the first String:

```js
var str = "transaction_id=0815/2009;transaction_cid=54AB;item_id=402163045080;item_va lue=25.20;item_quantity=1;transaction_id=0815/2009;transaction_cid=54AB;item_id=402163045080;item_value=25.20;item_quantity=1;";

console.log(encodeURIComponent(str.split(';').filter(a=>a).join('&')));
```